# How to output jquery var from this countdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retreive and use the variable of seconds from this countdown into my html =>
http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html

Here it's the js file from the project =>
http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/TimeCircles.js

In my html I call the variable by this way =>

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.total_seconds').text(total_duration.toFixed(2));
});
</script>

 <div id="total">Total :<br><span class="total_seconds"></span> &euro;</div>
```

But nothing print actually ...

If I put a test var into the top of js file I can output it but I don't know how to extract when it's into the main function

```
var total_duration = 'test';

(function($) {
[...]
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable `total_duration`? In the code you provided, it is `undefined`, which is why you see no change.

Comment: I want to take and use the seconds in this countdown http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/TimeCircles.js but I don't know how to extract it and the variable I must use, that's perhaps not the total_duration

Comment: You can't just use any variable defined within functions, as they are not visible outside their scope. If you **must** use TimeCircles, perhaps this is what you need: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php#func_getTime

Comment: Thanks, this getTime() function is near the things I want to do.
But how I take this function and use it into my html ?
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var total_duration = $("#MyDiv").TimeCircles().getTime();
    $('.total_seconds').text(total_duration.toFixed(2));
    });
   
    </script>
This way don't work

Comment: Please, read the [documentation to TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php). You seem to not be initializing the library properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I have a feeling this TimeCircles library is not what you want, as it seems to be made to [provide visitors an attractive countdown or timer](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php), which I read as "not a datetime library). You can simly use [Javascript's `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for date/time access and manipulation:

```js
$(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date('2018-01-01');
  $('.test').text((then - now) / 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Seconds until 2018: <span class="test"></span>
```

If that is not what you want, I suggest taking a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).